# Кабак по случаю дня сисадмина

Tags: алгоритм

На праздник сисадмина товарищи решили сходить в бар. Все они дано не виделись и сели за круглый стол. Их было поровну: `50%` предпочитали `*nix`, а `50%` - семейство `Windows`. Поскольку у администраторов Windows бороды нет, они купили сок, *nix админы взяли пиво. Так как официантка не разбирается в ОС, она все перепутала и большинству достался не свой напиток. Все уже хотели ее потроллить, но она предложила повернуть стол таким образом, что, не передвигая напитки, большинство получит свой заказ. Во всех ли случаях у нее это получится?

Comment: не во всех)

Comment: Да потому что сказано "большинство"!

Comment: @Flash спорим ты чемпион игры в напёрсток :)

Comment: Имхо, или условие не совсем точное, или админов не может быть нечётное количество.

Comment: Конечно, ответ может быть типа "Нет если админов нечётное колво". Но я не знаю как это доказать.

Comment: Не понял про наперсток)

Comment: @flash выбор из ограниченного количества вариантов. Если бить наугад, а именно так выглядел твой коммент, то с определёной вероятностью можно дать правильный ответ.  
По аналогии с анекдотом:  
Надпись на могиле "Здесь лежит Flash -- чемпион игры в напёрсток".  
Надпись на соседней "Или здесь".

Comment: @zenith, Их четное количество (2 раза по N).

Comment: блин, пропустил  что их парное количество) тогда да . всегда

Comment: "они дано не .."

дано????

да**в**но

Comment: Сходите лучше на брейн ринг

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Самый плохой вариант - когда все получили неправильный напиток.
Самый хороший - когда все получили свой. Между ними находится нормальное распределение, 
центр которого, когда половина получила то, что хотела.
Соответственно, вращая стол, мы будем колебать его вокруг точки равновесия, где амплитуда зависит от самого плохого расположения при данной последовательности стаканов.
Худший для официантки случай, когда колебаний не происходит.
Пример:

```
11110000  
11001100  
vvxxvvxx
```

при повороте:

```
11110000  
01100110  
xvvxvxxv
```

Упс:
По условию, БОЛЬШИНСТВО получило неправильный напиток.

Для непонятливых:

**Ответ: WIN, всегда получится**

Comment: В вашем примере не выполняется начальное условие. Изначально большинство получило не свой напиток. а у вас половина. т.е. не больше. С таким распределением неинтересно.

Comment: Нет. У меня, как раз большинство. Половина рассмотрена как граничный случай, который не выполнится по условию. Читайте внимательно.

Comment: "и большинству достался не свой напиток." это не граничный случай, а вырожденный.

Comment: Совершенно верно. См последнюю строчку.

Comment: Ну так это ложная посылка. Вы говорите, что да, не всегда у нее получится, потому что есть случай при котором начальное условие не выполняется. Отсюда может следовать любое утверждение.

Надо исследовать случаи типа:

    11110000
    10001110

Comment: В указанном вами варианте опять ровно половина недовольных.

11110000  
10001110
2  

11110000  
01000111  
2

11110000  
10100011  
2

Дальше продолжать?

Когда недовольные присутствуют, обязательно будут колебания, так как в противном случае это означало бы, что официантка принесла неверное количество напитков

Comment: Продолжим? :)

1. Не доказано, что циклический сдвиг также как и распределение всех комбинаций будет нормальным. Циклический сдвиг будет подмножеством, но не обязательно также распределенным.
2. Не доказано, что при циклическом сдвиге будут колебания. Даже наоборот, у вас колебаний нет, значит можно предположить что существуют и другие случаи когда колебаний не будет.
3. Доказательство можно свести к тому, что можно сдвигать стол на любое количество разрядов. Например, на 2 или на n/2 и, ваш пример даст то же ложное утверждение, что типа всегда получится, на самом деле далеко не всегда.

Answer (score 7):

У нее получится во всех случаях, потомо, что: Количество админов будет парное, тоесть 2 либо 4 и тд. Если большинству не достался свой напиток, то он не достался либо n/2+1 админам (в случае 6, 10, 14 (когда mod(n/2)=1)) либо n/2+2(8, 12 (mod(n/2)=0)) админам, это значит, что их было больше чем 4. Мой ответ: у нее получится повернуть стол таким образом, что, не передвигая напитки, большинство получит свой заказ, только в случае, когда будет больше, чем 4 админа.

Answer (score 6):

Так как 50/50, то если поставить стаканы в через один (сок, пиво, сок, пивО) - то покрутив стол - получаем профит, при условии, что виновники торжества, тоже сели через один.

Если бородатые на одной стороне, а форточники на другой - тогда тоже получится, если стаканы поставить в очередности (соки, пиво).

Еще как вариант можно крутить это "барабан" пока они не разберут, кто что хочет, тогда вообще без проблем и Якубович доволен.

Всех админов с праздником! хотя это и не ваш форум =)

**UPD**

Рассмотрим еще частных случай, если их пришло всего 2е - тогда профит 100%

Comment: @Gorets, Думаю лучше доказывать от обратного.

Comment: я сначала думал... потом решил, что эти 3 варианта - все что может решить проблему, остальное - официантка попала... разве что ей ужасно повезет =)

Answer (score 6):

Нет, поскольку есть как минимум один случай, когда это не возможно. Если все сисадмины будут сидеть попеременно, а напитки идти по порядку сначала пиво, затем сок (или наоборот), то как бы она не крутила стол напитки всегда будут соответствовать только у половины сисадминов.

```
     + +             + -             + -
     W L             W L             W L
   ┌─────┐         ┌─────┐         ┌─────┐
  ┌┘ b j └┐       ┌┘ b b └┐       ┌┘ b b └┐
-L│ b   j │W-   -L│ b   j │W-   -L│ b   b │W+
  │       │       │       │       │       │
+W│ b   j │L+   +W│ b   j │L+   -W│ j   j │L+
  └┐ b j ┌┘       └┐ j j ┌┘       └┐ j j ┌┘ 
   └─────┘         └─────┘         └─────┘
     L W             L W             L W
     - -             + -             + -
```

Comment: Ага. Но есть условие: УЖЕ большинство получило неправильный.

Comment: Спектр, зачем уже буянишь? Стол сломал в кабаке...

Comment: Пардон, не внимательно прочитал. В таком случае ответ: ответ да, получится, поскольку это данный случай единственный, когда у нее это не получится. Осталось только доказать почему :)

Comment: Чёт столы в разных браузерах по-разному поломаны

Comment: Пофиксил столы. Теперь они кроссбраузерные :)

Comment: Cтолы Ilyapirogoff(tm).

Answer (score 4):

Ответ на вопрос: не во всех случаях; если представить, что все - и админы, и напитки расположены рандомно за столом, на столе, то вероятность удачного случая можно рассчитать по формуле `(A+B)!/(A! * 2(A+B))` (или что-то около того).

Comment: хотелось бы взглянуть на это объяснение на плюсах или джаве, в идеале, конечно же, на баше админа

Answer (score 4):

Т.к. число админов четное минимальное значение тех кто получил свой напиток это половина, а половина-это не большинство, поэтому не во всех.

Answer (score 3):

Если они будут сидеть 2л-1в-2л-3в то не получится.
Правдиво и обратное, если на местах виндузятников будут сидеть красноглазые.
То есть если "группу" линукс\виндовс-пользователей будет разбавлять их "противник" - официантка не выполнит своего обещания.
Если же они будут чередоваться в последовательности в-л-в-л-.. или в-в-л-л.., то официантке необходимо будет повернуть стол всего на 10-30 градусов в зависимости от количества человек.

Comment: Допустим их 8 (или n, где n - любое четное число)
Стол круглый, поэтому все сидят друг против друга.
Если одну условную половину стола "разбавить" "противником" - то, как ни крути, не попадешь.

Сделаем наглядную схему
л - в | 
в - л |
л - в |
л - в |
(Ах да, я не умею в столбцы и ASCII)

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим ситуации при повороте стола на 1 человека:

1. напиток не соответствовал человеку и не стал соответствовать,
2. напиток не соответствовал человеку и стал соответствовать,
3. напиток соответствовал человеку и не стал соответствовать,
4. напиток соответствовал человеку и стал соответствовать.

Ситуации 1 и 4 не меняют ничего, 2 или 3 меняют количество нужных нам человек.
Если мы повернем стол на 360 градусов, то каждый напиток того самого вида будут иметь равное количество ситуаций, только они будут чередоваться с периодом 1. Gоскольку на данный момент у нас худшее состояние, то при некотором повороте мы можем сделать лучшее состояние.

Answer (score 3):

У меня такой вариант:

Циклический сдвиг для N разрядов N раз (т.е. 360 градусов), т.е. все варианты поворотов стола даст нам для каждого разряда ровно N/2 совпадений (просто просуммируем их)

```
11110000
01111000
00111100
00011110
00001111
10000111
11000011
11100001
--------
44444444
```

То, есть для любого расставленного заказа и для любой рассадки собутыльников при полном обороте стола каждый из них получит (и не получит тоже) свой напиток одинаковое количество раз, а именно N/2. А всего попаданий будет N*N/2, всегда.

Теперь допустим, что после каждого из N поворотов стола всегда количество участников с чужим напитком будет больше (только тогда официант будет неправ), приходим к противоречию что сумма N чисел больших N/2 должна быть в точности равна N*N/2.

Answer (score 3):

Не во всех. К примеру, 4 человека. И сели они через одного - unix, windows, unix, windows.

```
W________U 
|сок пиво|
|сок пиво|
U________W
```

Даже если она будет крутить стол - напитки будут соответствовать только у половины админов.

Comment: По условию у большинства уже не свой напиток, а у Вас поровну.

Answer (score 3):

По условию, рассмотрим только случай, когда большинство не получило свой напиток, а про все остальные случаи просто забудем. Определяющим предложением здесь является то, что представителей `*nix` и `windows` 50 на 50. И так, у скольких ребят из `windows` не свой напиток, у стольких ребят из `nix` опять же не свой. Учитывая предыдущее предложение, отсюда следует то, что крутя стол, мы получим случай, когда `nix`'ы и `windows`'ы поменяют свои напитки и ситуация поменяется в обратную сторону, т. е большинство получит свои напитки. Можно запустить програмку-перебор с использование функции `random`, которая работала бы следующим образом: для определённого случая, когда большинство не получило свой напиток, крутит стол и фиксирует тот момент, когда большинство получает свой напиток. Дальше меняет этот самый случай на другой произвольный, удовлетворяющий условию, и опять же крутит стол. Таким образом, для какого то миллиона случаев, мы экспериментально доказываем требуемое.